# Reference for a result in measure theory

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-sets

I'm studying the Aldous-Hoover Theorem and I've seen in many references that its analogous in dimension zero is a result of abstract measure theory:

> Let $\nu:E\rightarrow [0,1]$ be a Borel probability measure on a standard Borel space $E$. Then there is a measurable $f:[0,1]\rightarrow E$ such that, given a random variable $U\sim U[0,1]$, \begin{equation*}f(U)=^d X,\end{equation*}where $X$ is a random variable with values in $E$ and law $\nu$.

I am interested in seeing the proof of this result. Can you tell me where to find it?

Thank you

Comment: Are you interested in the proof, or for a reference of the proof?

Comment: I am interested in the proof. If you also give me a reference it's better! Thanks!

Comment: You may see Durrett's book probability theory and examples which is freely available online. For the proof look at the theorem 1.2.2 page 9.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't seem to be the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this result in Kallenberg's book *Foundations of Modern Probability*. It is Lemma 2.22 in the first edition and Lemma 3.22 in the second edition. Kallenberg states the result in a more general way involving a probability kernel $\mu\colon S\rightsquigarrow T$. But the result you want is the special case when $S$ is the one-point space, in which case $\mu$ is just a probability measure on $T$.